# Sequelize AfterHook won't call when use set or add mixin for a many-to-many associatoin

Tags: sequelize.js, version, hook, audit

I am using sequelize-verion (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-version) to keep of update to our table, it use afterHook to keep trace of create, update, destroy etc. It work for normal table. However, it seems that it won't work for relationship table.

I create model and many-to-many relationship as the following.

```
const ModelA = sequelize.define('tableA', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  dataA:  { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
});

const ModelB = sequelize.define('tableB', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  dataB:  { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
});

const ModalAModalB = sequelize.define('tableA_B', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  modelAId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  modelBId: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
});

const relationshipAB = ModelA.belongsToMany(ModelB, {
  through: 'tableA_B',
  foreignKey: 'modelAId',
  as: 'childrendB',
});


ModalAModalB.belongsTo(ModelA, {
  foreignKey: 'modelAId',
});
ModalAModalB.belongsTo(ModelB, {
  foreignKey: 'modelBId',
});

const ModelAVersion = new Version(ModelA);
const ModalAModalBVersion = new Version(ModalAModalB);
```

I try to create new modelA by the following.

```
await ModelA.sequelize.transaction(async () => {
  modelAdded = await ModelA.create({ ...newModelA });
  const modelBs = await ModelB.findAll({ where: { id: { [Op.in]: modelAChildrendBIds } } });
  await modelAdded.addChildrendB(modelBs);
});
```

However, the ModelAVersion can log the new entry, but not the ModalAModalBVersion table,

I try to passed individualHooks option, but it still doesn't work

```
await modelAdded.addChildrendB(modelBs, { individualHooks: true });
```

I have also tried the hook option as the following, it doesn't work either.

```
const relationshipAB = ModelA.belongsToMany(ModelB, {
  through: 'tableA_B',
  foreignKey: 'modelAId',
  as: 'childrendB',
  hooks: true,
});
```

However, the following work and both ModelAVersion and ModalAModalBVersion got updated.

```
  await modelBs.bulkCreate(
      modelBs.map((o) => ({
        modelBId: o.id,
        modelAId: modelAdded.id,
    })),
  );
```

Any idea how to make sequalize fire the aferHook for the relationship table when update on the many to many association through set or add methods?

Remark: the mixIn methods that I am following are describe in https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html.

Comment: I've found that hooks fire when `hooks: true` is added as an option inside each of your `belongsToMany` relationships.  Make sure `hooks: true` is added on both sides.  `individualHooks: true` should exist on your add/delete mixins, just like you described. If this works for you, I can post as an answer.